# knockout pass JSON param to click event

Tags: knockout.js

I have the following html:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-bind="click: update.bind($data, '{ "label": "dwsqa" }')">Yes / No</a>
```

and js:

```
self.update = function (config) {
    console.log(config);
};
```

And I have error:

```
Uncaught Error: Unable to parse bindings.
Message: SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token;
Bindings value: click: update.bind($data, '{
```

What's wrong here? How can I fix that problem?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your json has one line structure and quotes are correct.